# Medical image segmentation: maximum surface distance of 3D images in python?

Tags: image-segmentation, medical, semantic-segmentation

Is there any python package that has the function to calculate maximum surface distance between the segmentation result and ground truth?

Thanks

Comment: what you mean by _surface distance_, explain please.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Evaluate neural network using predicted image and ground truth image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61575961/evaluate-neural-network-using-predicted-image-and-ground-truth-image)